Critical points of $f(x) = \vert x + 1 \vert + \vert x - 1 \vert $
I have this function $f(x) = \vert x + 1 \vert + \vert x - 1 \vert $. We can write this function as follows.
$$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-2x  & \text{ for }  x \leqslant -1 \\[2ex]
2 &  \text{ for } -1 < x < 1  \\[2ex]
2x  &  \text{ for }  x \geqslant 1
\end{cases} $$
There are cusps at $x = \pm 1$. So derivative is not defined at those points in the domain $\mathbb{R}$. $f'(x) = 0$ for $x \in (-1,1)$. So, critical points are closed interval $[-1,1]$.
Is this correct ?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

As noticed in the comments, for this kind of questions, we should always post also the definition we are referring to since this is an issue depending primarily on that.
For example, according to this definition

a critical point of a function of a single real variable, $f (x)$, is a value $x_0$ in the domain of $f$ where $f$ is not differentiable or its derivative is $0 $

your answer is right, critical points are in the interval $[-1,1]$.

The OP should have posted his definition.

@GEdgar I’ve added something on that to make clear that what matters is indeed the definition. Thanks
